# Does this SE have a reddit approach to voting?

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious as to what exactly is the deal with all these extremely down-voted questions. Does this SE really just attract a higher than usual amount of really poor quality questions or is there some herd-mentality voting going on?

The Music SE is the one I have been most active on. It has its share of low-quality questions but it seems there, there is at least an attempt to get a good question out of the poster before downvoting. Here there are a lot of votes but not as much attempt to improve questions.

I'm not extremely active on the SE so I'm curious as to what exactly is the deal.

Comment: Whats reddit?...

Comment: Worth reading some of the questions that are heavily downvoted :-)

Comment: This topic comes up quite often so I'd suggest searching through earlier questions on this. I'd say that generally we tend to have a large volume of off-topic / poor quality questions come in. Many of those can be improved and made on-topic and as I've said before I think the community does a fine job at that. But a substantial amount is just not a good fit for the site or never sees an update with additional info from the OP and remains closed and down-voted. I'd wager that we do attract more of this type of input than other sites because we're less technical but still have a narrow scope.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know about the Music SE, but here the definition of the downvote is

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
> useful.

I take it at face value. I assume downvoters have read the question and concluded that either it doesn't show any research effort, that it is unclear, or that it is not useful.

I see a lot of comments attempting to clarify questions. I often don't see any responses or attempt to edit the question by the original poster.

I also know that some people have their own personal reasons for downvoting, or voting to close. I may not agree with their reasons, but on a highly gamified site like SE, it's not at all surprising that this happens.

I don't know what "a Reddit approach to voting might be", nor do I care in this context.